# Как найти самое длинное слово в textarea на Js

Tags: javascript

Есть `button`,`h1` и `textarea` мне нужно найти самое длинное слово в  `textarea`

```js
function c3() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value
  txt = txt.split("")
  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    if (txt[i].length > max.length) {
      max = txt[i]
      document.getElementById("pr3").innerHTML = txt
    }
  }
  console.log(max)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) + [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function fn() {
  let max = document.getElementById('ta').value.split(' ')
    .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
  console.log(max);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="ta">long very_long</textarea></br>
<input type="button" value="go!" onclick="fn();" />
```

Comment: Можно дописать используя initialValue,если окажется несколько слов с одинаковой длиной

Comment: [Если надо найти все слова из текста независимо от того какие могут быть символы, работает c utf-8.](https://gist.github.com/iliyaZelenko/77494f5e3f4d26f30fdc750d2693d336)